# Deleting broken repository in Bonobo

Tags: windows, git, bonobo

I had some sort of errant script that somehow put a copy of a repo in my Bonobo server. Then Bonobo picked it up with the message `Discovered in file system`. I deleted it from said filesystem but now I can't get it to delete from bonobo, I have a `(missing)` tag on the repo.

I tried to reform it and clone to establish all the links but there is a space in the repo name and I can't clone it. It chops the URL up at the space and fails. The correct working repo in this folder is this file without the space so I have to be careful with what I do.
So I thought I would try to delete the repo using the web ui. I click delete and nothing happens. I don't see any processing errors. Nothing in the error files. Nothing in the developer tools that say the request happened.

Anybody have any ideas on how to get this repo out of my server?

Answer (score 4):

Downloaded a sqlite browser and nuked the offending row.

`\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data` had the file `Bonobo.Git.Server.db`. I perused the schema for a bit to make sure I didn't violate an fk and safely deleted the row that was giving me issue. It no longer shows up as a repository and I have removed it from the repo directory.

Comment: _you might wanna edit this to your answer_ - download and run sqllite.exe. use `.open c:\\wwwroot\\Bonobo.Git.Server\\App_Data\\Bonobo.Git.Server.db` to open the bonobo database. Delete the Repo row with `delete from Repository where name = 'theMissingRepoName';`